Converting Excel cell function to Google Sheets function
So I have this cell function I found for an Excel workbook
=FILTER(A1:B29,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,A1:A29)),"None")
I want to put into this Google workbook I have.  I would just use Excel for this workbook but there would be a lot of reformatting if I convert it to an Excel workbook.
How would I change this to make it work in Google Sheets?

remove the ,"None"

@Scott Craner's comment actually answers the question. Another method to write the formula is by using the QUERY function like this: =QUERY(A1:B29,"SELECT * WHERE A CONTAINS '"&C1&"'").
